# linux pdf file shows inode/x-empty

Tags: php, linux, file, pdf, mime-types

Is it possible to add the mime information to a file that you know is a pdf. We are being sent pdf files from an automated program and they are not showing as pdf's but we know they are.

I get

```
MAIL-g0Ja1L.PDF: inode/x-empty; charset=binary
```

where as pdf's sent through manually from customers are being read correctly:

```
MAIL-moJQ0x.PDF: application/pdf; charset=binary
```

Comment: add information where? sent how? this question lacks a lot of basic information

Comment: Modify the file so that it is read as a pdf like the correct one. I'm not sure how they are being sent from the customers side. But we are retrieving them as attachments to emails.

Comment: php is horrible when things concern mime-type detection.